# How do you get multiple views in one window like JSFiddle does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a website and hybrid mobile app that has multiple views in one window similar to how JSFiddle one view for HTML, CSS, JavaScript and the Results in one window. I have attached a screenshot of JSFiddle window below

[image: JSFiddle Window]

Comment: First step at learning how other sites do things is to look at the source code, most browsers have a view page source option

Comment: Try googling javascript splitter pane or splitter bar.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#72328c86068c58bb245fc96697a63629

Look into a splitter. [jqxSplitter](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxsplitter/index.htm#demos/jqxsplitter/nested-splitters.htm) is probably the most popular library I've come across for this. (and works well with [mobile devices](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#72328c86068c58bb245fc96697a63629))

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#mainSplitter").jqxSplitter({
    width: 850,
    height: 850,
    orientation: "horizontal",
    panels: [{
      size: 300,
      collapsible: false
    }]
  });
  $("#firstNested").jqxSplitter({
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    orientation: "vertical",
    panels: [{
      size: 300,
      collapsible: false
    }]
  });
  $("#secondNested").jqxSplitter({
    width: "100%", 
    height: "100%", 
    orientation: "horizontal",
    panels: [{ size: 150 }]
  });
  $("#thirdNested").jqxSplitter({
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%", 
    orientation: "horizontal",
    panels: [{
      size: 150,
      collapsible: false
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxsplitter.js"></script>

<div id="mainSplitter">
  <div>
    <div id="firstNested">
      <div>
        <div id="secondNested">
          <div>
            <span>Panel 1</span></div>
          <div>
            <span>Panel 2</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>Panel 3</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="thirdNested">
      <div>
        <span>Panel 4</span></div>
      <div>
        <span>Panel 5</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question...

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Comment: To whom thumbed down. Please state why.